# Slider plugin working locally but not live?

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider

I am using a slider plugin here http://emmaholisticmassage.com/home.html.

It works locally but not live. I have tried different versions of jQuery, some stop it working locally, but none seem to work live. In firebug I get 403 forbidden warnings.

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: Open the dev console and you will see where is the problem. (a.k.a it's not loading the css and js, don't know if you included them or mistyped the location to them)

Comment: thanks, I found it was the permission settings.